# WPF - Adding multiple files to listview from drop event

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

So my problem comes when I drag multiple files in to my application, and I have no problem with adding one file to a listView.

The problem comes when I'm trying to add multiple files into the listView.

And I expect that it might have something to do with the way I'm adding the files to the list view.

Only the first file is added to the listView when I drag and drop them in to my application, and I need all the files to get added to the list.

How can I make this happen? (i.e: how far off am I?)

Any help is appreciated!

But anyway... Here's what I've got so far:

```
 <ListView x:Name="scanQueue" ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" Margin="0,122,0,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And the code behind:

```
 public class items
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Size { get; set; }

        }

        public IList<items> itemList { get; set; }

        public void addToList(string name, string size)
        {
            itemList = new List<items>()
            {
               new items() {Name=name, Size=size }
            };
         }
```

And I think, the problem I'm having here is that I try to add my data into two columns in the listView.

So, this is the method where the magic should happen:

```
 private void Window_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                long byteSize = fi.Length;
                string stringSize = BytesToString(byteSize);
                string name = fi.Name;
                addToList(name, stringSize);
            }
    }
```

I now read through this and realize that I'm not explaining this very well... But I hope someone understands my question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so this was much simpler than I thought... Feel rather stupid now.
It might not be the most beautiful implementation I've ever done.

This little beauty here is the one that alluded me!

```
 scanQueue.Items.Add(new { itemName = name, itemSize = stringSize });
```

```cs
  public class items
        {
            public string itemName { get; set; }
            public string itemSize { get; set; }

        }

        List<string> test = new List<string>();

        public void Window_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            List<string> fileList = new List<string>(files);

            foreach (string file in fileList)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
                long byteSize = fi.Length;
                string stringSize = BytesToString(byteSize);
                string name = fi.Name;
                scanQueue.Items.Add(new { itemName = name, itemSize = stringSize });
            }
            fileList.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is instead of using an IList I would use an ObservableCollection. Second thing is once you verify (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop); returns the multiple files as expected I will change the method addToList to

```
public void addToList(string name, string size)
    {
        itemList.Add( new items() {Name=name, Size=size });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, ok so that's what I did. That for some reason gives me a NullReferenceException - for some reason. Thanks for helping me out.